# STILL the url not allowed by the application config?

Tags: php, facebook

I still can't figure out why I'm getting this error:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more
>   of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match
>   the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of
>   one of the App's domains.

I've gone through several of the questions on this site and I have the website listed on the oath site in the advanced tab and the two places on the basic page (image shown below). I copied and pasted the appID and APPsecret multiple times and tried leaving the whitelist IP's blank to see if that helped but it didn't. I'm pulling my hair out here!

Any idea why this might be happening??[image]

[image]

Comment: This really isn't a PHP question right? or am I missing something?

Comment: The error message you get is pretty clear: You are putting URLs in a place (somewhere not on the screenshots you joined) where they must be subdomains or your 'prayerpond.com' domain.

Comment: But where? I don't have any urls anywhere that aren't prayerpond.com

Comment: Were you able to get this sorted? When and where do you see the error? App dashboard or elsewhere?